# nuxt fonts cors issue with cdn(cloudfront)

Tags: nginx, cors, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have some fonts support by cloudfront like following:
https://xxx.cloudfront.net/_nuxt/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f.ttf

The file could be download success in chrome, same as the origin file (https://example.com/_nuxt/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f.ttf).

But I get error in chrome dev console, and the fonts not working.

> Access to Font at 'https://xxx.cloudfront.net/_nuxt/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f.ttf' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

here is my cloudfront settings

[image]

[image]

nginx setting:

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com *.example.com;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* (Jorgee) ) {
     return 403;
  }

#  I try to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header here, but not working
#  location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg|font.css)$ {
#    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
#  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
  }

}
```

Result of curl

curl -I https://xxx.cloudfront.net/_nuxt/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f.ttf

```
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/x-font-ttf
content-length: 165548
date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:43:21 GMT
server: nginx
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
last-modified: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 01:47:18 GMT
etag: W/"286ac-162bcaf7470"
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 20ec3b4214c4cf2bbb05faf96ff61033.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: I-b_DNfst4q48vJtNRrzxCX2uSNi6yO1_BFSPVuWxRP1Q5Ii6AElUQ==
```

curl -I https://example.com/_nuxt/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f.ttf

```
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:45:28 GMT
content-type: application/x-font-ttf
content-length: 165548
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
last-modified: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 01:47:18 GMT
etag: W/"286ac-162bcaf7470"
```

Anyone can give me some idea~??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx setting should be

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    if ($request_uri ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg|font.css)$) {
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest your font-specific nginx configuration block within your `location /` block, like so:

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com *.example.com;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* (Jorgee) ) {
    return 403;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;

    location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg|font.css)$ {
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just finished it, restart nginx and invalidate cloudfront by `/*` , but nothing change ..

Comment: the fonts will return 404 not found after I nest the location block, but I don't know why?